# Serial Port Communication HandFlow in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I need to send and receive data from a [AD101B](http://www.hbm.com/fileadmin/mediapool/hbmdoc/technical/i2048.pdf) board by rs232 serial  port to my own c# application. So I made a trace to the suplier application. I obtained the data connection, baud rate, parity, stopbyte, etc.

```
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
            port.PortName = p_strPortName;                 //COM1
            port.BaudRate = p_uBaudRate;                   //9600
            port.DataBits = p_uDataBits;                   //8
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;                  //1
            port.Parity = Parity.None;                     //None
            port.ReadTimeout = p_uReadTimeout;             //300
            port.WriteTimeout = p_uWriteTimeout;           //300
            port.Open();
```

I couldn't set the following values in the SerialPort class

```
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW: Set handshake information
ControlHandShake=1
FlowReplace=64
XonLimit=0
XoffLimit=0
```

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073963/serial-ports-how-do-i-set-characters) it was useful, but I cant set the value of FlowReplace or ControlHandShake, because they aren't part of the [DCB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

If anyone knows how set the HandFlow value in C# or how to establish the connection between AD101B device and   C # application it  would help me.

Comment: You are looking at the driver IOCTL.  Set the SerialPort.Handshake property to none and DtrEnable to true.  The rest don't matter.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/856414/Change-DCB-fields-from-SerialPort-instance-Csharp